# Linked-list and generic type

Tags: c#, generics, linked-list, msdn

I am learning C# generic types, and I have gotten really confused by the linked-list example in the Generic module on MSDN website :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x6a29h6.aspx

I pasted the code here: 
My confusion is about :

```
private Node next;
```

**how should I understand this line of code?** 
 I only can think it is a private field that is created with class name?

```
 public Node Next                   
 {
   get { return next; }
   set { next = value; }
 }
```

**I guess this is a property with class name as its type ?**

```
private Node head;
```

**Why does the nested class name appear where supposed to be the type of head ?**
**is this a private field of class  `GenericList<T>` ?**

```
// type parameter T in angle brackets 
public class GenericList<T> 
{
    // The nested class is also generic on T. 
    private class Node
    {
        // T used in non-generic constructor. 
        public Node(T t)
        {
            next = null;
            data = t;
        }

        **private Node next;**    // How should I
        public Node Next
        {
            get { return next; }
            set { next = value; }
        }

        // T as private member data type. 
        private T data;

        // T as return type of property. 
        public T Data  
        {
            get { return data; }
            set { data = value; }
        }
    }

    private Node head;

    // constructor 
    public GenericList() 
    {
        head = null;
    }

    // T as method parameter type: 
    public void AddHead(T t) 
    {
        Node n = new Node(t);
        n.Next = head;
        head = n;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        Node current = head;

        while (current != null)
        {
            yield return current.Data;
            current = current.Next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's little or no magic here. `private Node next;` is a private field named `next` whose data type is `Node`. That's exactly the same thing as if it had said `private int next;`. No magic.

Comment: @JohnSaunders hey, John I see your point here, but it still not quiet answers my question here:   how does it make the code work by creating a field that is the nested class type  Node ?    I mean the Node class doesn't return any type , and plus field 'next'  is defined as null whenever a Node instance is created.

Comment: @EdwardSun Your question seem to really boil down to "What is a class in C#" ... may be a bit too broad for SO... "class doesn't return any type" is very strange statement and hard to provide concrete help with.

Comment: There's an entire manual on the C# Programming Language. You should look at it before asking basic questions on the syntax of the language. See [C# Programming Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx) . For detailed reference, see the [C# Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/618ayhy6.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> private Node next;
> ```
>
> how should I understand this line of code?

`next` is a private field of type `Node`

> ```
> public Node Next                   
> {
>     get { return next; }
>     set { next = value; }
> }
> ```
>
> I guess this is a property with class name as its type ?

it's a property named `Next` which type is `Node`

> ```
> private Node head;
> ```
>
> Why does the nested class name appear where supposed to be the type of head ?
>   is this a private field of class `GenericList<T>` ?

because it's the type of `head` and yes it's a private field of the outer class.

There's nothing special in here, a class can have field, properties, etc. with same type as itself

***Edit*** regarding the comment "how does it make the code work by creating a field that is the nested class type Node ? (...) plus field 'next' is defined as null whenever a Node instance is created"

All the "magic" lies in the AddHead method.
When you create an instance GenericList (say GenericList) at first `head` is null
so after this step we could say the list can be represented as **[]**

Then you call AddHead(1) for example ; it creates a Node with that value, then **sets it's Next to the current head** and finally makes that newly created Node as the new head.
so after this step the list is : **1 -> []** (a head with 1 which links to it's next node ; the null node aka the empty list)

After that if you call again AddHead with say 2 ; you'll end with something like : **2 -> 1 -> []**

And when comes time to iterate over you simply have to loop while the head isn't empty (aka null), read it's stored value and use the linked node (it's next) as the "new head"